# MVC Ajax Handle Response Correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying implement some Ajax and have run into an issue with how the response is handled and also how to correctly deal with the data.

My JavaScript code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#creatediaryentry').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                dataType: "json",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#diary-entries-list').append("<li>" + result + "</li>");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This takes a simple form data and posts it as expected to the controller method:

```
    public JsonResult PostNewEntry(EntryViewModel entry)
    {
        var entryDc = Mapper.Map<EntryViewModel, EntryDc>(entry);

        try
        {
            //_apiClient.SubmitNewEntry(entryDc);
        }
        catch (ApiClientException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse());
    }
```

Whats happening at the moment is the response is loaded into an empty page with just the SuccessResponse content - `{"Success":true}`

What I'd ideally like to do is just grab the Text the user entered in the UI and update the `<li>` with the client side data without sending it back from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try preventing the default submit behavior. You can use `preventDefault` method to do so.

```
$(function(){  
  $('#creatediaryentry').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      //your other ajax posting code goes here

  });
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  What variable in the Ajax call can be used to reference the form?

Comment: @Jammer You can refer the form by selecting it with the ID of that.

Comment: Indeed I had a go immediately after posting (Duh!) and it worked: $('#newdiaryentry').val()